# c# Replace text within curly brackets, including the curly brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace a string,enclosed in curly brackets.

If I use the Replace method provided by the Regex class and I don't specify the curly brackets, the string is found and replaced correctly, but if I do specify the curly brackets like this: `{{FullName}}`, the text is left untouched.

```
   var pattern = "{{" + keyValue.Key + "}}";
   docText = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(docText, keyValue.Value);
```

Take this string as a example

`Dear {{FullName}}`

I want to replace it with `John`, so that the text ends up like this:

`Dear John`.

How can I express the regex, so that the string is found and replace correctly?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue with [this code](https://pastebin.com/3GPzZmcj). The `docText` variable after the third line will be `Hello there John!`.

Comment: I think this is rather unclear right now. What is `keyValue`? Please provide all details to repro the issue.

Comment: Also, you might want to look up [RegEx.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2) to sanitize your pattern string so that you match all the characters of the "pattern" literally.  You don't actually have a regular expression there.  e.g.:  `{` means something special in RegEx language.

Comment: Yes, `{{8}}` will not match `{{8}}`, true, so `{`s should be escaped. `Regex.Escape` is always a good idea if one is not sure of what kind of chars there are in `keyValue.Key`.

Comment: The key is only half the problem.  The braces of `{{foo}}` is also a problem must become `\{\{foo\}\}`.  Just pass `new Regex(Regex.Escape(pattern), ...)`  That will turn your so-called _pattern_ (which is actually not a pattern at all, but literal text to search for) into an actual regular expression _pattern_.

Comment: Regex.Escape produces this string \{\{FullName}}

Comment: It doesn't escape the trailing curly braces

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regular expression if the key is just a string.  Just replace "{{FullName}}" with "John".  example:

```
string template = "Dear {{FullName}}";
string result = template.Replace("{{" + keyValue.Key + "}}", keyValue.Value);
```

**Edit: addressing concerns that this doesn't work...**

The following is a complete example.  You can run it at https://dotnetfiddle.net/wnIkvf

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var keyValue = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("FullName", "John");
        string docText = "Dear {{FullName}}";
        string result = docText.Replace("{{" + keyValue.Key + "}}", keyValue.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I tried that, and it doesn't work. The text used comes from a word file (.docx), does it change the way the replace method works?

Comment: @eddy I added a dotnetfiddle that demonstrates it working.

Comment: @eddy provided that docText winds up being an unremarkable string free of strange unicode characters or control sequences, then it should be fine.  Examine the docText in your debugger to see what's in it.

Comment: Sorry @Wyck but this is a *one trick pony* … see my answer.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var keyValue = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("FullName", "John");
var pattern = "{{" + keyValue.Key + "}}";
Console.WriteLine(new Regex(Regex.Escape(pattern), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace("Dear {{FullName}}", keyValue.Value));
```

Output:

```
Dear John
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for `"Dear {{FullName}}"` to `"Dear John"`?

not a regex solution... but this is how I prefer to do it sometimes.

```
string s = "Dear {{FullName}}";
// use regex to replace FullName like you mentioned before, then...
s.Replace("{",string.empty);
s.Replace("}",string.empty);
```

Comment: I don't think this is right.  I expect OP wants string interpolation, meaning they would want "FullName {{FullName}}" to result in "FullName John"

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use a regular expression, then escape your literal text to turn it into a regular expression pattern using [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
var keyValue = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("FullName", "John");
string docText = "Dear {{FullName}}";
var pattern = "{{" + keyValue.Key + "}}";
docText = new Regex(Regex.Escape(pattern), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(docText, keyValue.Value);
```

docText will be `Dear John`

Comment: Regex.Escape produces this string `\{\{FullName}}`

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is that you really want to do is replace multiple things in a document.

To do so use the regex pattern I provide, but also use the regex replace match evaluator delegate. What that does, is that every match can be *actively* evaluated for each item and a proper item will be replaced as per C# logic.

Here is an example with two possible keywords setup.

```
string text = "Dear {{FullName}}, I {{UserName}} am writing to say what a great answer!";

string pattern = @"\{\{(?<Keyword>[^}]+)\}\}";

var replacements 
   = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "FullName", "OmegaMan" }, { "UserName", "eddy" } };

Regex.Replace(text, pattern, mt =>
{

    return replacements.ContainsKey(mt.Groups["Keyword"].Value)
           ? replacements[mt.Groups["Keyword"].Value]
           : "???";

}
);
```

**Result**

> Dear OmegaMan, I eddy am writing to say what a great answer!

---

The preceding example uses

- [Match Evaluator Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- Named match capture groups `(?<{Name here}> …)`
- Set Negation `[^ ]` which says match until the negated item is found, in this case a closing curly `}`.